# how to substring and return the value in between the blacket

Tags: vb.net

How can i substring the string, e.g. **"A1(Value)"** and return me the **"Value"**?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `RegularExpression`:

```
Dim str = "A1(Value)...(anotherValue)"
Dim pattern = "\(([^)]*)\)"
Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled)
Dim firstBracket = regex.Match(str)
If firstBracket.Value.Length <> 0 Then
    Dim inFirstBracket = firstBracket.Value.Substring(1, firstBracket.Value.Length - 2)
    'Value'
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out with regex

```
Dim result As String
Dim txt As String ="A1(Value)"
Dim re1 As String=".*?"
Dim re2 As String="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"
Dim r As Regex = new Regex(re1+re2,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim m As Match = r.Match(txt)
If (m.Success) Then
    Dim word1=m.Groups(1)
    result = word1.ToString()
End If
```

Got it from: http://txt2re.com/index-vb.php3?s=A1%28Value%29&2

---

Or just split the string from the 3rd char to length-1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a regular expression then you can use `IndexOf` to find the locations of the brackets and `SubString` to return to portion of the string within the brackets:

```
Dim txt As String = "A1(Value)"
Debug.WriteLine(txt.Substring(txt.IndexOf("(") + 1, txt.IndexOf(")") - txt.IndexOf("(") - 1))
```

Note that if the string does not contain an open and a close bracket this will throw an exception so you might want to add some error checking